# What is the principal branch of $f(z)=\sqrt{1-z}$, $z\in\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, definition

My question is, essencially, about the definition of the principal branch of a function that is not a Logarithm. In this case, $f(z)=\sqrt{1-z}$.

Comment: It is a $\log$, unlucky.

Comment: How can it be a log?

Comment: You have to choose a "branch" of $\log(1-z)$; and then $f(z)=\exp(\frac12 \log(1-z))$

Comment: @OhMyGod As pointed out by Etienne, $\sqrt\cdot$ is just shorthand for the above.

Comment: then it would be $f(z)=\sqrt{|1-z|}e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}$, where the square root is the positive branch?